# What does "[ OK ] Reached target Network is Online." message on startup mean?

Tags: networking, network-manager, startup, systemd, adapter

I have noticed that when starting my installation of Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 I get the following message:

```
[ OK ] Reached target Network is Online.
```

However I know for sure that my machine is not connected to the internet because I don't have Wifi and my Ethernet cable is not plugged in... So is this a bug where it thinks that it is connected to the network when it is not? Or does it simply mean that the Network Adapter is online?

Also, in `syslog` this is how the message looks:

```
Feb 25 12:25:26 NowWhat systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
```

Comment: Does this reveal the correct message? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep target`

Comment: @chili555: Nope, there is no output for that command... I will just have to check next time I restart my machine and correct the message here if it is wrong, anyway, I think that it is close enough to the real thing.

Comment: If the syslog has been archived and a new one started recently, it may be in syslog.1: `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep target`

Comment: @chili555: Ok, thanks! I found it and have now updated my question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message in syslog, `systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online` is related to *systemd*. It simply means that the networking stack is up, that networking devices have been discovered and, if possible, a driver has been associated and that, again, if possible, an IP address assigned.

This does not indicate that the system is connected to the internet. That depends on, among other things, the state of the wireless switch, ethernet cable, whether networking is enabled in Network Manager, etc.